# Rails: how and where to add this method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app where I retrieve a list of users from a specific country.

I did this in the `UsersController`:

```
@fromcanada = User.find(:all, :conditions => { :country => 'canada' })
```

and then turned it into a scope on the `User` model

```
scope :canada, where(:country => 'Canada').order('created_at DESC')
```

but I also want to be able to retrieve a random person or multiple persons from the country. I found this method that's supposed to be an efficient way to retrieve a random user from the database.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.random
      if (c = count) != 0
        find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, I have a few questions about how to add it, and how the syntax works.

1. Where would I put that code? Direct in the `User` model?
2. Syntax: so that I don't use code that I don't understand, can you explain how the syntax is working? I don't get  (`c = count`). What is `count` counting?  What is `rand(c)` doing? Is it finding the first one starting at the offset? If `rand` is an expensive method (hence the need to create a different more efficient `random` method), why use the expensive '`rand`' in this new more efficient `random` method?
3. How could I add the call to `random` on my `find` method in the `UsersController`? How to add it to the scope in the model?
4. Building on question 3, is there a way to get two or three random users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't monkey patch that (or anything else!) into ActiveRecord, putting that into your User would make more sense.

The `count` is counting how many elements there are in your table and storing that number in `c`. Then [`rand(c)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) gives you a random integer in the interval `[0,c)` (i.e. `0 <= rand(c) < c`). The `:offset` works the way you think it does.

`rand` isn't terribly expensive but doing `order by random()` inside the database can be very expensive. The `random` method that you're looking at is just a convenient way to get a random record/object from the database.

Adding it to your own User would look something like this:

```
def self.random
  n = scoped.count
  scoped.offset(rand(n)).first
end
```

That would allow you to chain `random` after a bunch of scopes:

```
u = User.canadians_eh.some_other_scope.random
```

but the result of `random` would be a single user so your chaining would stop there.

If you wanted multiple users you'd want to call `random` multiple times until you got the number of users you wanted. You could try this:

```
def self.random
  n = scoped.count
  scoped.offset(rand(n))
end

us = User.canadians_eh.random.limit(3)
```

to get three random users but the users would be clustered together in whatever order the database ended up with after your other scopes and that's probably not what you're after. If you want three you'd be better off with something like this:

```
# In User...
def self.random
  n = scoped.count
  scoped.offset(rand(n)).first
end

# Somewhere else...
scopes = User.canadians_eh.some_other_scope
users  = 3.times.each_with_object([]) do |_, users|
  users << scopes.random
  scopes = scopes.where('id != :latest', :latest => users.last.id)
end
```

You'd just grab a random user, update your scope chain to exclude them, and repeat until you're done. You would, of course, want to make sure you had three users first.

You might want to move the ordering out of your `canada` scope: one scope, one task.

Answer (score 0):

1. That code is injecting a new method into ActiveRecord::Base.  I would put it in lib/ext/activerecord/base.rb.  But you can put it anywhere you want.
2. count is a method being called on self. self will be some class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base, eg. User.  User.count returns the number of user records (sql: `SELECT count(*) from users;`). rand is a ruby stdlib method [Kernel#rand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand). `rand(c)` returns a random integer in the Range `0...c` and c was previously computed by calling #count. rand is not expensive.
3. You don't call random with find, User#random is a find, it returns one random record from all User records. In your controller you say User.random and it returns a single random record (or nil if there are no user records at all).
4. modify the AR::Base::random method like so:

   ```
   module ActiveRecord
     class Base
       def self.random( how_many = 1 )
         if (c = count) != 0
           res = (0..how_many).inject([]) do |m,i|
             m << find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
           end
           how_many == 1 ? res.first : res
         end
       end
     end
   end

   User.random(3)  # => [<User Rand1>,<User Rand2>,<User Rand3>]
   ```